# jquery anchor animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to animate the scroll on an anchor link and getting error:

Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

This the the js:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

And this is the html:

```
<li><a href="index.html#r">My anchor link</a></li>
```

Comment: how about a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5XRj3/. Are you redirecting to the `index.html` file (i.e. are you navigating to the anchor on another page)? Also, does the element with the attribute `name="r"` exist? You might be confusing the `name` and `id` attributes.

Comment: anchor link works but not animation. I'm working on the fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong: *$.attr(this, 'href').substr(1)* , use this the get the href attrib:

> $(this).attr('href');

Here you are the working code. First I extract the anchor name, then I use it:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var name = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('#')+1);

    $('html, body').animate({   
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + name + '"]').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`offset` method returns an `undefined` value for empty collections. It seems your selector doesn't select any element. You can check the `length` of the collection or the returned value of the `offset` before reading the `top` property.

And as a note if you want to get the `hash` of the anchor, you can use the `hash` property, `this.hash` where `this` refers to a `HTMLAnchorElement` element.